# Why does putting sudo umount /mnt into a shell script fail to execute, but succeed on the command line?

Tags: linux, debian, shell

When I was executing the following script in the `Debian 12 live` environment, I found that I couldn't `umount /mnt` in this script. The prompt was `/mnt : target is busy`. However, after the script was executed, I was able to successfully execute `sudo umount /mnt` on the command line. I have already added 777 permissions to this script. What is the problem?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
set +x
current_path=$(pwd)
echo $current_path
hdstr=/dev/mmcblk0
hdstr1=${hdstr}p1
hdstr2=${hdstr}p2
hdstr3=${hdstr}p3

root_path=/mnt
boot_path=${root_path}/boot
grub_path=${boot_path}/grub
efi_path=${boot_path}/efi

lib64_path=${root_path}/lib64
bin_path=${root_path}/bin
lib_path=${root_path}/lib

echo "debug:function definition"
    
execute_command() {
    local command=$1
    eval "$command"
    local status=$?
    if [ $status -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "run the cmd:$command success"
    else
        echo "failed to run the cmd:$command" 
        exit 1
    fi
}

add_env_for_chroot() {
    echo "add env for chroot"
    execute_command "sudo mkdir -p ${lib64_path}"
    execute_command "sudo ln -s ${lib_path} ${lib64_path}"
    execute_command "sudo cp ${lib_path}/* ${lib64_path}/ -nra"
}


change_root() {
    echo "change root"
    #execute_command "sudo mount --rbind /dev  /mnt/dev"
    #execute_command "sudo mount --rbind /proc /mnt/proc"
    #execute_command "sudo mount --rbind /sys  /mnt/sys"
    execute_command "sudo mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc"
    execute_command "sudo mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys"
    execute_command "sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev"
    execute_command "sudo mount --bind /run /mnt/run"
    add_env_for_chroot

    
    cat << EOF | sudo chroot ${root_path}
    grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/mmcblk0 --force --recheck --efi-directory=/boot/efi 
    exit
EOF
}

create_fstab() {
    echo "create fstab"
    UUID1=$(sudo blkid | grep '^/dev/mmcblk0p1' | awk -F 'UUID="' '{print $2}' | awk -F '"' '{print $1}')
    UUID2=$(sudo blkid | grep '^/dev/mmcblk0p2' | awk -F 'UUID="' '{print $2}' | awk -F '"' '{print $1}')
    UUID3=$(sudo blkid | grep '^/dev/mmcblk0p3' | awk -F 'UUID="' '{print $2}' | awk -F '"' '{print $1}')
    #这里不替换sda
    devName="\/dev\/mmcblk0p1"
    UUIDStr="UUID=$UUID1"
    execute_command "sed -i \"s/${devName}/${UUIDStr}/g\"  /mnt/etc/fstab"
    
    devName="\/dev\/mmcblk0p2"
    UUIDStr="UUID=$UUID2"
    execute_command "sed -i \"s/${devName}/${UUIDStr}/g\"  /mnt/etc/fstab"
    
    devName="\/dev\/mmcblk0p3"
    UUIDStr="UUID=$UUID3"
    execute_command "sed -i \"s/${devName}/${UUIDStr}/g\"  /mnt/etc/fstab"
}

partition_format_mount() {
    echo "begin to part"
    ####partition####
    sudo /sbin/parted ${hdstr} mklabel gpt
    sudo /sbin/parted ${hdstr} <<EOT 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null || exit 1
    rm 1
    rm 2
    rm 3
    rm 4
    mkpart primary fat32 1MiB 200MiB
    set 1 esp on
    mkpart primary ext4 200MiB 8200MiB
    mkpart primary ext4 8200MiB 100%
    quit
EOT
    echo ""
    ####format####
    echo "begin to format"
    #execute_command "sudo partx ${hdstr} 1>/dev/null"
    execute_command "sudo /sbin/mkfs.fat -F32 ${hdstr1} 1>/dev/null"
    execute_command "sudo /sbin/mkfs.ext4 ${hdstr2} 1>/dev/null"
    execute_command "sudo /sbin/mkfs.ext4 ${hdstr3} 1>/dev/null"
    
    execute_command "sudo /sbin/fsck.vfat -v -a -w ${hdstr1} 1>/dev/null"
    execute_command "sudo /sbin/fsck.ext4 ${hdstr2}"
    execute_command "sudo /sbin/fsck.ext4 ${hdstr3}"
    ####mount####
    execute_command "sudo mkdir -p ${root_path}"
    execute_command "sudo mount ${hdstr3} ${root_path} 1>/dev/null"
    execute_command "sudo mkdir ${boot_path} -p"
    execute_command "sudo mount ${hdstr2} ${boot_path} 1>/dev/null"
    execute_command "sudo mkdir ${efi_path} -p"
    execute_command "sudo mount ${hdstr1} ${efi_path} 1>/dev/null"
    echo "end part"
}

install_os(){
    echo "begin to install grub"
    execute_command "sudo mkdir -p ${grub_path}"
    execute_command "sudo cp ${current_path}/grub_CRA.cfg ${grub_path}/grub.cfg"


    #execute_command "sudo cp ${current_path}/x86_64-efi  /usr/lib/grub/  -raf"  #issue1
    execute_command "sudo cp \"${current_path}/bzImage\" ${boot_path}/"        #2024-1-19 修改bzImage路径
    execute_command "sudo cp \"${current_path}/initrd.img-6.4.0-rt8\" ${boot_path}"  #2024-1-19 修改initrd路径
    execute_command "sudo cp \"${current_path}/rootfs.tar.gz\" ${root_path}"
    cd ${root_path}
    execute_command "sudo tar -vxf rootfs.tar.gz"
    execute_command "echo \"y\" | sudo rm rootfs.tar.gz"
    echo "begin to changerooot" 
    change_root
    create_fstab
    
    echo "start to umount"  
    execute_command "sudo umount ${hdstr1} 1>/dev/null"
    execute_command "sudo umount ${hdstr2} 1>/dev/null"
    execute_command "sudo umount /mnt/run"
    #execute_command "sudo umount /mnt/{proc,sys,dev}"
    execute_command "sudo umount /mnt/proc"
    execute_command "sudo umount /mnt/sys"
    execute_command "sudo umount /mnt/dev"
    #cat << EOF | sudo chroot ${root_path}
    #echo "To successfully umount /mnt, I don't know why, but it is useful." 
    #exit
#EOF
    execute_command "sync"
#==========================my question in here=============================
    sudo umount /mnt 
#==========================================================================
#   execute_command "sudo umount ${hdstr3} 1>/dev/null"
    #sudo /sbin/fsck.vfat -a ${hdstr1}
    #sudo /sbin/fsck.ext4 -a ${hdstr2}
    #sudo /sbin/fsck.ext4 -a ${hdstr3}
    execute_command "sync" 
}

mainFunc(){
    echo "start to burn"
    partition_format_mount
    install_os    
}

mainFunc
```

Comment: For general shell scripting best practice, I recommend using ShellCheck on your script.

Comment: `chmod 777` is an _incredibly_ bad idea. Your default should be `755`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You've got the equivalent of `cd /mnt` further up the script, so you're in the directory you're trying to unmount.

There are also some other big issues here to consider:

1. Just about every command in the script runs under `sudo`, so consider removing all those calls to `sudo` and requiring the script itself to run under `sudo`.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   if [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]
   then
       echo "Please re-run with sudo" >&2
       exit 1
   fi
   ```

   Or even just have the script re-run itself under `sudo` automatically:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   if [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]
   then
       echo "Re-running with sudo" >&2
       exec sudo "$0" "$@"
       exit 1
   fi
   ```
2. You're storing commands in variables. That can cause all sorts of quoting-related problems, exacerbated by you using `eval`. Variables are for data, and functions are for commands:

   ```
   execute_command() {
       if "$@"
       then
           echo "ran $1 successfully" >&2
       else
           echo "failed to run $1" >&2
           exit 1
       fi
   }

   execute_command sudo umount /mnt/proc
   ```

   But actually that can be achieved simply by setting `-e` (or maybe `-ex`, where the `-x` flag enables line-by-line tracing) on the first line or using `set -e` and maybe `set -x` shortly afterwards. For example,

   ```
   #!/bin/bash -ex
   echo "this line succeeds"
   echo "the next line will fail"
   false
   echo "the script has already stopped so you will not see this"
   exit 0
   ```
3. You're not double-quoting any of your variables. That means they are subject to splitting and globbing whenever you use them.
4. "*I have already added 777 permissions to this script*" - there's presumably no need to allow other users to edit this script, so don't give away that right. At best allow other users to run the script:

   ```
   chmod u=rwx,go=rx ./your_script    # Replace "./yourscript" with the script path
   ```

Comment: Some of the easy fixes can be checked automatically with ShellCheck. It makes writing bash a little more bearable.

Comment: I'd consider `else rc=$?; echo "Failed to run $1" >&2; exit "$rc"` so we respect the exit status of the thing that failed, rather than squashing everything down to 1.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not sure that adds value. Programmatically what would it mean for the script to exit with (say) status 2 as opposed to status 1?

Comment: @ChrisDavies, traditionally, UNIX tools have man pages describing the meaning of each possible exit status. If the OP's script is calling, say, rsync -- then rsync exit status values are meaningful; or if it's a command-not-found error we can expect exit status 254, as is conventional there. Granted, being able to look up a precise mapping does depend on there being _one specific tool_ that's expected to fail, but it's still better to preserve information than throw it away.

Comment: (boo, hiss re: `set -e`, btw -- enables wildly [version-dependent and shell-specific behavior](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/) and adds [unintuitive corner cases](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises), making desk-checking all but impossible)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy exactly. So if the script exits with any given status how you you tell - programmatically - which component failed? Without that knowledge you can't usefully interpret the status value. What might make sense is to exit with a different status code when an error occurs in different parts of the script, but that's different yet again

Comment: @ChrisDavies, that's a question with a context-dependent answer -- but _as a rule_, if you preserve data there's a chance someone can make sense of it later, but if you throw it away it's gone forever. Yes, it's work for a human to say "the logs indicate this exited at step X, and exit status Y means Z in this context"; but if you preserve that data, it's there for analysis. (In practice, including `$rc` in the `echo` may be more useful, but again, that doesn't happen _unless it's captured_)

Answer (score 3):

You need to exit the chroot env before umount partitions. By `exit` command.

Use bash `getopts`, to make your script accept the unmount function as parameter. Or use `trap` to execute a function on bash script exit:

```
unmount_fscks (){
commands_umount_fsck_here
}

trap 'unmount_fscks' EXIT
```

Comment: I have an `exit` after the grub install function in `change_root()`, is that correct?

Comment: @justSoSo it's unnecessary because the subshell you've set up would have exited immediately anyway